# Activerecord Force Index with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I am trying to construct an ActiveRecord statement that forces an index, whilst also using includes.

The statement looks something like:

```
Job.from("jobs FORCE INDEX(index1,index2)").includes(:workflow)
```

however it seems AR doesn't like this and throws:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `map' for "jobs FORCE INDEX(index1,index2)":Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral):
```

Has anyone got any idea? All works okay if the includes statement is taken off so I assume it is trying to build the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and table aliasing query...

Thanks
M

Comment: Seems to work okay in rails 4. Might worth exploring the differences between from in rails 3 and rails 4 (http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.11/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from)

Comment: Hi Shadwell. it works fine except if activerecord has to perform a query based on one of the includes. So a fuller example would be Job.from("jobs FORCE INDEX(index1,index2)").includes(:workflow).where("workflows.name = 'Bob'")...

Comment: You'll need to add a `references` call: `where("workflows.name = 'Bob'").references('workflows')`

Comment: Hi Shadwell - thanks, I thought it might be this, but we are using Rails 3.2.19; is there anything that can support it in Rails 3? Thanks

Comment: Nope, totally stumped. I've tried it on rails 3 now and it also works fine for me. You'll need to post your full stacktrace. Is it possible you're using a `Job` class that has been extended or isn't an ActiveRecord class?

Comment: Just realised. It's the count function that it is bombing out on: Job.from("jobs FORCE INDEX(index1,index2)").includes(:workflow).where("workflows.name = 'Bob'").count

Comment: I ran into the same thing, and created a Rails bug for it. Still a problem with Rails v4.2.6 https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24193

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments on the question it turns out that the `count` call on a chain that has `from` and `includes` (with a condition on the included association) is the problem.

In fact it seems that just using a `from` call even if it is just `from("jobs")` will cause the problem so the force index is a bit of a red herring.

I can't find a solution for using `includes` in this case (where a count is required). However, if you are including an association and adding a condition for it then `joins` should be equivalent to `includes` anyway (I think!). In which case the following should work (I've broken it down into steps to make it more visible):

```
 q = Job.from("jobs FORCE INDEX(index1,index2)")
 q = q.joins(:workflow)
 q = q.where("workflows.name = 'Bob'")
 q.count
```

If you really do need the left outer that `includes` provides then you can specify that manually:

```
 q = Job.from("jobs FORCE INDEX(index1,index2)")
 q = q.joins("left outer join workflows on workflows.job_id = jobs.id")
 q = q.where("workflows.name = 'Bob'")
 q.count
```

Comment: Note: rails 4 or rails 3 was a red herring also. This should solve the problem on both rails 4 and rails 3.

Comment: Awesome Shadwell. Didn't know about that syntax for joins (or rather, never occurred to me I could do that)!